# setting default item on dropdownlistfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have populated a selectlist in my viewmodel in the form:

```
 DeliveryCentres = new SelectList(deliveryCentres, "Id", "CentreName");
```

in my View I have:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DeliveryCentreId, Model.DeliveryCentres, "-- Not Required --");
```

The problem is that on display the dropdown defaults to the first item in the list as opposed to the **-- Not Required --** value.

How do I make this the default?

Comment: The selected value  will be whatever the value of `DeliveryCentreId` is. If its value is `null` or does not match one of the option values, then the "Not Required" option will be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Stephen Muecke has answered the question. I just needed to leave the ID as null in the ViewModel before rendering.

From comments:

> The selected value will be whatever the value of DeliveryCentreId is. If its value is null or does not match one of the option values, then the "Not Required" option will be selected

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. OP found the answer in a _comment_ below their post. They now post it as an answer and give appropriate credit here.